# Elevation and Azimuth of satellite in different location

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements, ephemeris, two-line-elements, rinex

I know the Elevation and Azimuth of the a specific GPS satellite (I have the [RINEX files](https://igscb.jpl.nasa.gov/igscb/data/format/rinex211.txt) of the station in a specific Location 4.4801,-73.3433; in order to calculate this), but I want to know the elevation and azimuth of that same GPS satellite at around 200-500 km away (e.g. 7.11392,-73.1198). At the moment I have no idea how do this? any idea?

**Note:**
The RINEX file of a *GPS* satellite has some data (ephemeris variables) to re-calculate the position (elevation and azimuth), but the RINEX files for the *GLONASS* constellation have the position of the satellite in cartesian coordinates; that will be somewhat difficult (I don`t know yet if impossible).

**Note 2**:
I tried before to "predict" the position using [TLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) files with the library *[Pyephem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/)*, but the position over time has some significant error. (like this)[image]

**Note 3:**
I got a better accuracy with TLE files, the information is [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20887/prn-number-in-tle-files-are-the-same-in-rinex-files-in-gps-constellation). However, it will be good to get the answer.

thanks.

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you want to do this like this? It sounds like a difficult way to to get the apparent position. If you can use TLEs, what is your interest in trying to use RINEX? Also, do you have a link for a simple definition/explanation of what a RINEX file really is? The link in your question is long but I can't figure out what it really is. Thanks!